# Turn two lines result query in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id | municipio_id |  ano | populacao
 1 |            0 | 2010 |      5000
 2 |            0 | 2011 |      5000
```

I create a query:

```
SELECT
case when ano = 2010 then populacao end a2010,
case when ano = 2011 then populacao end a2011
FROM populacao
where municipio_id = 0
```

The result is:

```
a2010 | a2011    
 5000 |  null
 null |  5000
```

I need like below:

```
a2010 | a2011    
 5000 |  5000
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(case when ano = 2010 then populacao end) as a2010,
       SUM(case when ano = 2011 then populacao end) as a2011
FROM populacao
WHERE municipio_id = 0;
```

If you want it for all municipios, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT municipio_id,
       SUM(case when ano = 2010 then populacao end) as a2010,
       SUM(case when ano = 2011 then populacao end) as a2011
FROM populacao
GROUP BY municipio_id;
```